# Reliably interpret MySQL datetime value as UTC in Node.js code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, mysql2

I have an annoying problem where the same MySQL `datetime` value is interpreted differently in my developer environment and in the test environment.

In the MySQL database, it's stored as follows (in both environments).

`2021-04-07 04:30:21`

There's no timezone information here (e.g. ISO-8601 representation).  So I think it's up to the client to decide on the timezone for this stored date/time.

The Node.js code is using the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) library to interface with the database.

In the test environment, reading the above date/time correctly adjusts it to local time for me:

`Wed Apr 07 2021 14:30:21 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)`

However, in my development environment, the date/time value is unchanged but it's incorrectly interpreted as a date/time in the local timezone:

`Wed Apr 07 2021 04:30:21 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)`

I'm not sure where the problem lies.  Presumably the test server has been configured differently to my development environment.  Any ideas where the problem may lie?

**Further information**

MySQL table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `payment_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=94 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Cut-down version of JavaScript code used to read values:

```
api_helpers.pool.execute("SELECT * FROM `payments`",
    [],
    function (err, payments) {
        callback(err, payments);
    }
);
```

where `api_helpers.pool` is a pool created via the mysql2 `createPool` function.

If I then loop through `payments` and do `console.log(payment.payment_date);` it prints out the incorrect date as described above.

Comment: Please show the definition of the database table and the JavaScript code used.

Comment: @NineBerry - I edited the post to add this information.

Comment: Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html